# Algorithms for identifying differences between two trees

Tags: c#, computer-science

I am trying to work on a program that will highlight the differences between some custom project files.

I would like to load my project files into a custom tree structure and annotate the two trees with additions, deletions & modifications. I can parse the project files into a tree structure without issue but am stuck on doing the diff.

I have been looking at various papers on methods for computing the differences between ordered trees but haven't been able to wrap  my head around them enough to produce a working implementation.

I have mainly focused on the original paper:
[Simple fast algorithms for the editing distance between trees and related problems](http://www.grantjenks.com/wiki/_media/ideas:simple_fast_algorithms_for_the_editing_distance_between_tree_and_related_problems.pdf)

I would like to implement my project in c# ideally there would be a library for this but I haven't been able to find one. I have found a few implementations in [other languages](https://github.com/timtadh/zhang-shasha/blob/master/zss/compare.py) but they don't really contain much on how the process works, and therefore I believe I would have a hard time troubleshooting & testing if just trying to port the code directly.

Are there any c# libraries I have missed, or alternately are there any libraries written for other languages that are well documented in terms of algorithm that I could use as the base for porting the code.